# How set ticks invisible but leave tick-lables are visible

Tags: python, matplotlib

I plot a clock panel as:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create a polar coordinates
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

# set ticks and labels
angles = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 12, endpoint=False))
labels = [str(l) for l in range(12)]
ax.set_xticks(angles, labels)
ax.set_yticks([])
```

It display as:

[image]

I want to set the ticks invisible but leave labels visible and tried adding line `ax.set_xticks([])`

Then all the ticks and tick-labels disappear.

How could I set ticks invisible but leave tick-labels visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your ticks transparent with `ax.tick_params(grid_alpha=0)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Create a polar coordinates
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, polar=True)

# set ticks and labels
angles = np.radians(np.linspace(0, 360, 12, endpoint=False))
labels = [str(l) for l in range(12)]
ax.set_xticks(angles, labels)
ax.tick_params(grid_alpha=0)
ax.set_yticks([])

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Note: this also works with `ax.tick_params(grid_linestyle='')` or `ax.tick_params(grid_linewidth=0)`